# how do you get to the very top of the highest mountain in skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I play Skyrim Xbox 360 edition and I heard that at the very top of the mountain like the tip of it, is an easter egg thats a Enchanted pick but I do not know how to go past the Greybeards court yard. there is a big door way but I cannot pass, for there is a wind that hurts me. I tried using shouts but that did not work; even the Become Ethereal shout, but it did not work. How do I get to the very top of this mountain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ascend to the Throat of the World normally you would need the Clear Skies shout which is learned from the Greybeards as part of the Main Quest, right after the Alduin's Wall quest.

It is also possible to climb up before you get the shout by jumping on the nearby rocks but its a tedious task.

The pickaxe in question is the [Notched Pickaxe](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Notched_Pickaxe) which is the only item enchanted with the [Smithing Expertise](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Smithing_Expertise) enchantment.

Exact location:

Comment: Would be better if it addressed the pickaxe, since that seems to be the motivation for the question.

Answer (score 6):

### Without Doing The Quest Line

You need to be playing the main quest line in order to be able to climb the Throat of the World. It is however, possible to do it without having to do the quest line:

**Short Answer:** Get a horse, and climb the mountain without running into any pathways. These paths will have wind that will damage your health.

**Long Answer:** A horse is recommended for climbing mountains, since it can overtake any obstacles better than your character. When you reach the courtyard of High Hrothgar, start riding your horse on the right side, do not go past the gate. Go as high as you can. Note that winds will appear on the walking pathways that lead to the top, so don't end up there, just stay away. Soon, you'll reach the top of the world without sacrificing your character.

### Doing The Quest Line

**Short Answer:** After finishing "Alduin's Wall", the Greybeards will give you a shout to get rid of the winds later in the game.

**Long Answer:** After you completed "Alduin's Wall", Delphine tells you to go to the Greybeards to learn the Dragonrend shout. Then the Greybeards will give you a shout called "Clear Skies" (all three words). By using all three words, you are able to get rid of the winds that can kill your character. Note that there are more than one dangerous wind while walking the pathway to the top. Keep using your shout whenever you reach an area with dangerous wind. In a few minutes, you'll reach the top.

This "enchanted pickaxe" you're looking for is called the "Notched Pickaxe". Some people say it's a reference to Notch, the co-founder of Mojang and the creator of Minecraft. However, some others disagree due to the fact the word "Notched" exists and has a meaning that might apply to the pickaxe.

Comment: thx for the help

Comment: And that pickaxe is indeed up at the top? Never noticed it. Where is it hidden?

Comment: @DCShannon I don't know it's exact location, but just go to the **VERY** top and you'll see it.